# Get input as hex and output as hex - msfvenom - Buffer Overflow - Bad characters stage - automate segregation

Tags: python, binary, hex, buffer-overflow

I have been trying to automate the Buffer overflows's bad characters segregation
eg: while checking for bad characters most of the time we have very less space to check the bad characters. For this we have to segregate the bad charactes as 6 and 6 and 6 and so on...

to automate this I tried to create script as below

```
kali@kali:~$ cat badchars.py 
str = ("\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff")

n = 50
for i in range(0, len(str), n):
        val = "Str = Str + " + '"' + str[i:i+n] + '"'
        print val
```

And this actually off course converts into ASCII I believe as below

```
kali@kali:~$ python badchars.py 
Str = Str + "


▒▒!"#$%&'()*+,-./01"
Str = Str + "23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abc"
Str = Str + "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~����������������������"
Str = Str + "some invalid chars"
Str = Str + "��������������������������������������������������"
Str = Str + "������"
```

I'm unable to find a way to get this print as the same a given value.